# How do i assign databases to rails projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Recently I cloned a rails project from github. I already had a database so I thought it didn't matter, but whenever I run rails server in my rails project, I get this error.

I noticed that there was no Database.yml file, too.

Here's the error-

```
All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:110:in `database_configuration': Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`: (RuntimeError)
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's typical in open source projects to not include the `database.yml` file b/c it has the passwords used to access the database (for each environment). So you should just create one.

For example, you can create a new rails project, and then copy the `database.yml` file (in the project's `config` directory) to your existing project. When you create the new project, you can specify the database that should be used:

```
rails new my_project -d mysql
```

From the documentation the databases you can specify are:

mysql, oracle, postgresql, sqlite3, frontbase, ibm_db, sqlserver, jdbcmysql, jdbcsqlite3, jdbcpostgresql, jdbc

Answer (score 0):

`Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"]`

It's a pretty clear error message, create the file following the pattern [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your rails project and you also have a database system installed and running (I recommend the amazing postgresql, but any database you're comfortable with is fine), just let your rails app know that you want to connect to it. You'll need to provide your username and password.

For PostgreSQL:

In gemfile:

```
gem 'pg'
```

Then install the gem:

```
bundle install
```

Then do from your rails app folder:

```
touch config/database.yml
```

This is a YAML file which you'll feed your connection details to. So open up your text editor and enter something like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: YOURUSERNAME
  password: YOURPASSWORD
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

development:
  <<: *default
  database: YOURAPPNAME_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: YOURAPPNAME_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: YOURAPPNAME
```

Finally, just go and create new empty databases with rake.

```
rake db:create
```

This should let you start your server:

```
rails s
```